# Does Html5 Fullscreen Api Work On Chrome Version 28

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, fullscreen, ipad-2

I want to know whether html5 fullscreen api works in iPad 2 Chrome version 28 or not?
I came to know that works in Android tablet chrome(version 28)

Regards,
Pranoopa

Answer (score 1):

Fullscreen is supported in Chrome for Android but no Chrome for iOS